# insert rows and increase a value in a field

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, insert

i have trouble with inserting from one table to another:
i want to insert in a table multiple rows from another one and when inserting, increase the value of a int field in the destination table.
the code is something like that:

```
 Dim sqlCmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
        Dim conMain As New SqlClient.SqlConnection()

    Dim strSQL As String = 
"INSERT INTO AvizeCorn 
(Seria, DataMAx, NrAviz, Agent, Școala, Data, 
Buc, ZileLivrare, Luna, Produs, Anul) 
SELECT @Seria, @Data+Zile as DataMax, @NrAviz, Agent, Școala, @Data, Zile*BucSt as Buc, 
Zile as ZileLivrare, @Luna, @Produs,@Anul 
FROM AgențiȘcoliCorn"

    Try
        conMain.ConnectionString = "Data Source=cristib\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Avize Măr și Corn;Integrated Security=True"
        sqlCmd.Connection = conMain
        conMain.Open()
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sqlCmd.CommandText = strSQL

        With sqlCmd.Parameters

            .AddWithValue("@Seria", "AGP")
            .AddWithValue("@NrAviz", DataSetCorn.AvizeCorn.Compute("Max(NrAviz)", "") + 1)
            .AddWithValue("@Data", Convert.ToDateTime(DataCorn.Text))
            .AddWithValue("@Luna", MonthName(Month(DataCorn.Text)))
            .AddWithValue("@Produs", Produs.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@Anul", Year(DataCorn.Text))

        End With

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conMain.Close()
        MsgBox("Avizele au fost create cu succes.")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

my problem is with `NrAviz`

i want to check the max value and increase by 1 for every row inserted in the table.
with my code it inserts the same value for every new row inserted in the table.

please help, as i'm a totally newbie in sql  and vb.net

Comment: How many rows now in the tables

Comment: You would be better to use IDENTITY or SEQUENCE.  Computing a sequence like this a) will probably not work in a multi-user environment and b) will be resource intensive.  What do you need it for?

Comment: in this new table i need a field (NrAviz) to be incremented as it is like an ID field. but i need it to be different from the ID field which exists already in my table and it is identity.
what about the SEQUENCE? how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `Max(NrAviz)` into the SELECT which is fetching the records to insert them. You can use `ROW_NUMBER`

```
Dim sqlCmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
Dim conMain As New SqlClient.SqlConnection()

       Try
        conMain.ConnectionString = "Data Source=cristib\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Avize Măr și Corn;Integrated Security=True"
        sqlCmd.Connection = conMain
        conMain.Open()
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sqlCmd.CommandText = strSQL


        Dim strSQL As String = "INSERT INTO AvizeCorn (Seria, DataMAx, NrAviz, Agent, Școala, Data, 
Buc, ZileLivrare, Luna, Produs, Anul) 
SELECT @Seria, @Data+Zile as DataMax, (SELECT MAX(NrAviz) from AvizeCorn) + row_number() over (order by ID), Agent, Școala, @Data, Zile*BucSt as Buc, 
Zile as ZileLivrare, @Luna, @Produs,@Anul 
FROM AgențiȘcoliCorn"

        sqlCmd.CommandText = strSQL

        With sqlCmd.Parameters

            .AddWithValue("@Seria", "AGP")
            .AddWithValue("@Data", Convert.ToDateTime(DataCorn.Text))
            .AddWithValue("@Luna", MonthName(Month(DataCorn.Text)))
            .AddWithValue("@Produs", Produs.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@Anul", Year(DataCorn.Text))

        End With

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conMain.Close()
        MsgBox("Avizele au fost create cu succes.")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

**EDIT**

You can also try with

```
INSERT INTO AvizeCorn (Seria, DataMAx, NrAviz, Agent, Școala, Data, Buc, ZileLivrare, Luna, Produs, Anul) 
SELECT @Seria, @Data+Zile as DataMax, MAX(NrAviz)+1 FROM AvizeCorn, Agent, Școala, @Data, Zile*BucSt as Buc, Zile as ZileLivrare, @Luna, @Produs,@Anul 
FROM AgențiȘcoliCorn
```

Comment: better approach ...but now it says "invalid column name "NrAviz".

Comment: Then `NrAviz` is not a column on `AgențiȘcoliCorn` table.  What is the table name which `Nraviz` column belongs to? is it `AvizeCorn`?

Comment: AvizeCorn. OK. i did modify that but now i'm where i was at the begining. it inserts 2 rows with same NRAviz value. max +1. does not increase the value for the next  row.

Comment: I've updated the answer to retrieve `Max(NrAviz)` from `AvizeCorn` table

Comment: how can i re-query the max value after the first row is inserted and then add 1?

Comment: By repeating the lines on which the SELECT is set and max value is obtained. See the edit

Comment: Depends on where do you want to re-query the max value.

Comment: after the first line is inserted, then after the second,...
excuse my lack of knowledge...

Comment: No worries at all. The best way is to retrieve the value each time you go to insert a line, always before inserting. This way you make sure that the line will be always inserted with the max value + 1

Comment: problem is that it inserts hundreds of rows at once...how to select max for each row ?

Comment: Ok I see. Sorry my bad!. I didn't realize you are inserting from a SELECT which is fetching a lot of rows. Then you'll need to recover the max value in the SELECT which is fecthing the results to insert them. The best way is to use `row_number()` functionality. I've edited the answer.

Comment: If it won't work, try with the alternative INSERT in the edit.

Comment: when using row_number()?

Comment: Man, you're goood.... the problem was in over (order by NrAviz)...should be over (order by ID)
Works now...

Comment: Ahhh..little typo. sorry. Is it finally working fine?